# Advice to revive deleted questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

I appreciate the concerns behind the closing of my questions. I understand some of the frustration that my questions might be conceived as primarily opinion-based and too broad. Let go through my questions and I hope I can receive advice on how to undelete these questions so that I can edit it to ask proper questions that fit this site regulations.

1. [What caused division and persecution in the history of Eastern Orthodox Church during the time of Patriarch Nikon of Moscow](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/37384/15492) This question was initially considered too broad. I've edited this question by narrowing it down to the time of Patriarch Nikon of Moscow. My main aim in asking this question is to give an awareness to people that Inquisition is not something unique in Roman Catholic Church. Most people who I've been conversed with didn't know about this past history of the Eastern Orthodox Church persecuting those sectarian believers within their jurisdictions. I would like to ask your support to undelete this question. Please help me to rephrase this question in such a way that it'd be acceptable with this site regulations. Would you give me a second chance to fix my question? I want to ask a historical fact question not an opinion based question. I'll give you an example: It's proper and valid within this site regulations to ask the doctrinal reasoning behind John Calvin's approval to burn Michael Servetus. Similarly I asked about what caused the persecution of Old Believers? Thank you for helping me out.
2. [What is the difference between Lutheran and Calvinist beliefs in the apostasy of the Church?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/38564/15492) This question is important for me because it asked the historical reasoning behind the early Reformation movement that the Church at that time was judged to lapse gradually into heresy and hence the need of Restoration. I've edited my question by making it a direct question specifically to Lutheranism and Calvinism as the two are initially one movement before the two later split over the Real Presence in the Holy Communion. Please help me to undelete this question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Users under 10K rep cannot see deleted posts. That limits who can help you.

Comment: I think your edits are good, but I can't see or help with the deleted questions. I'm sure a mod will help soon. You could flag your questions and ask for them to be undeleted too.

Comment: Yes, flag them with a custom reason and a mod can undelete them.